# A different vector product

Tags: linear-algebra

I am taking linear algebra, and have learned about the vector dot product and cross product.  Is there a vector product defined by :
    $(a_1, a_2, \dots ,a_n)\times (b_1, b_2, \dots,b_n) = (a_1b_1, a_2b_2, \dots ,a_nb_n)$ ?
If so, what it it called?

Comment: One place it shows up (annouyingly, at times) is in Mathematica: Multiplying two vectors using the operator "*" does entry-wise multiplication, whereas you need to use "." to take a dot product.

Comment: @Michael Hardy -- how did you do the subscripts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is called the *Hadamard product*. See http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard_product_(matrices)

According to this article, it is also referred to as the *Schur product* or the *entrywise product*.